# Angular universal build baseHref change breaks angular routing in app

Tags: aws-lambda, github-actions, serverless, angular-universal

I have an angular application set up to build prior to deployment to AWS lambda.  The `serverless.yml` file uses the `stage: production` entry, prefixing the deployment with `/production`.  When built and deployed this way, the generated styles, polyfills, and main js files return 403 errors.  If I change the production build `baseHref: production/` in angular.json, the files can be found when deployed, but the angular routing breaks due to an unmatching url segment 'production'.  Adding a production route to the angular routing breaks everything completely.  Is there a way to fix this pathing issue?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I certainly didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `deployUrl` option in `angular.json`

```
deployUrl: '/production/'
```